# Get value from ion-select and store it in localstorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic-vue

I want to save the value from the ion-select-option into the localstorage. However, it returns 'undefined'. I'm using Ionic and Vue 3.0.0.

How can I get the selected option and store it in the localstorage?

**Ion-select**:

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-select
  @ionChange="store(options)"
  v-model="options"
  placeholder="Kies status"
 >
 <ion-select-option
  v-for="option in options"
  v-bind:value="{ id: option.id, text: option.name }"
  v-bind:key="option"
 >
  {{ option.name }}
      </ion-select-option>
     </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

**Options**

````
return {
 selected: "",
   options: [
     { id: 1, name: "Gelezen" },
     { id: 2, name: "Nog niet gelezen" },
     { id: 3, name: "C" },
  ],```
````

**Method**

```
methods: {
  store(value) {
    const name = value.name;
    console.log("name" +name);
    const selected = localStorage.setItem("option", name);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected value from the `detail` property of the `CustomEvent` emitted:

Note that I removed the `(options)` from the event handler.

**Template:**

```
 <ion-select
  @ionChange="store"
  v-model="options"
  placeholder="Kies status"
 >
```

**Method:**

```
methods: {
  store(event) {
    const name = event.detail.value;
    console.log("name" + name);
    const selected = localStorage.setItem("option", name);
},
```

BTW `localStorage.setItem()` [always returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem#Return_value) so it doesn't make sense to save it to a variable (in your case `selected`.

Comment: I'm retrieving: [object Object]

Comment: Ah, that's because you set the value to an object (`{ id: option.id, text: option.name }`), so you'll have to use `event.detail.value.id` or `event.detail.value.name`.